# Synchronization of two noisy sinusoidals signals

Tags: signal-analysis, python, noise, phase

I have two noisy sinusoidal signals and I am currently investigating solutions to synchronize them using python. Here is an example I made to illustrate my goal, supposing that I generate these two sinusoidals (both with same frequency and amplitude but a phase difference):

```
time = np.arange(0, 60, 0.005)
amp = 2
F = 0.25
signal1 = amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*F*time + np.pi)
signal2 = amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*F*time + np.pi/3)

mu, sigma = 0.2, 0.1 # mean and standard deviation
noise1 = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, len(signal1))
noise2 = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, len(signal2))


noisy_signal1 = signal1 + noise1
noisy_signal2 = signal2 + noise2

plt.figure()
plt.plot(time, noisy_signal1)
plt.plot(time, noisy_signal2)
plt.show()
```

One of the possible solutions I have found was by Cross-Correlation, which would look like this:

```
def cross_correlation_using_fft(x, y):
    f1 = fft(x)
    f2 = fft(np.flipud(y))
    cc = np.real(ifft(f1 * f2))
    return fftshift(cc)

# shift < 0 means that y starts 'shift' time steps before x # shift > 0 means that y starts 'shift' time steps after x
def compute_shift(x, y):
    assert len(x) == len(y)
    c = cross_correlation_using_fft(x, y)
    assert len(c) == len(x)
    zero_index = int(len(x) / 2) - 1
    shift = zero_index - np.argmax(c)
    return shift

shift = compute_shift(noisy_signal1, noisy_signal2)

if shift < 0:
    noisy_signal1_sync = noisy_signal1[np.abs(shift):]
    noisy_signal2_sync = noisy_signal2[:len(noisy_signal1_sync)]
    
elif shift > 0:
    noisy_signal2_sync = noisy_signal2[np.abs(shift):]
    noisy_signal1_sync = noisy_signal1[:len(noisy_signal2_sync)]    
    

plt.figure()
plt.plot(noisy_signal1_sync)
plt.plot(noisy_signal2_sync)
plt.show()
```

I also saw that one different possible solution would be via frequency domain, yet, I am still unable to achieve a solution using that approach. I checking how it would work for my given example but I haven't found a solution yet. Therefore, my questions is regarding how to perform the synchronization of two noisy sinusoidal signals (same F and A) in the frequency domain.

EDIT1: The frequency and amplitudes are previously known. I am mostly interested in achieving the same results I had by using the cross-correlation. I learned that there is a way to achieve the same result by instead of shifting the sinusoidal via cross-correlation, to shift it via FFT/IFFT in the frequency domain, which is something that I do not understand yet and what the answer should address.

Comment: I'm not reading your python code.  Can you use $\LaTeX$ to express mathematically what you have and what you're trying to do?  Are you certain the two sinusoids have the same frequency? Do you want a phase lock loop (PLL)?

Comment: well, you're trying to cross-correlate two perfectly periodic signals. So, any solution would have periodic ambiguity. Is this what you mean being unable to achieve a solution? Or is it something else? Could you describe how the failure constitutes?

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to incorporate the above-requested information.  In particular, if the two sinusoids have the same frequency, and that frequency is known, then the problem becomes vastly simpler.

Comment: Made some adjustments. Hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the time-shift $\Delta t$, or how to actually shift the signal (in the frequency domain) once $\Delta t$ is known?